# How to get list of sheet names present in the excel and pass it to DataSet variable in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I want to get list of sheetnames present in an excel and pass each sheetname to DataSet variable

Answer (score 0):

ADF doesnt have any in built feature to get the list of Excel sheet names , so you would have to explicitly write a custom code to get that details.
For that you can leverage Azure automation account or databricks or Functions via either Python or powershell

Comment: Hey, the below blog might help in case if your ask here is to iterate across all files 
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/08/31/iterating-across-all-excel-sheets-dynamically-and-converting-into-csv-files-via-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline/